# Vue.js State Updates but View doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am enjoying learning Vue.js however I tend to keep running into the issue that when I set a data property based on state that it doesn't update the component if state changes.

For example...

Here are the snippets

```
<router-link v-if="!isDisabled" :to="{ path: '/effects' }">
   <button class="stepButton" :class="{ disabled: false }">Next</button>
</router-link>

<button v-else class="stepButton" :class="{ disabled: isDisabled }">Next</button>


data: function(){
            return {
                ailmentsLib: [
                    "Chronic Pain",
                    "Migraines",
                    "Muscle Spasms",
                    "Stress",
                    "Vertigo",
                    "Nausea"
                ],
                search: '',
                searchMatch: true,
                ailments: [
                    "Chronic Pain",
                    "Migraines",
                    "Muscle Spasms",
                    "Stress",
                    "Vertigo",
                    "Nausea"
                ],
                isDisabled: this.$store.state.ailment.length < 1 ? true : false
            }   
        }
```

I have the state as changing in my vue inspector but the button doesn't become enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `data()` does not react to changes in the `store`. You need to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to watch for state changes.
Example:

```
computed: {
    isDisabled: function ()  {
        return this.$store.state.ailment.length < 1
    }
}
```

Comment: to be more precise, `data` is reactive. but it's not set up to update automatically whenever `$store` changes

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getters if you need to manipulate the data and reuse it.
[Getters Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)